# Regular expression to finding position of a delimiter and remove all except third delimiter notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

text example:

```
ABC | 123 | target | abc.txt |

CDEFG | 12345 | target | [df:ejk] |
```

need to remove all except the "target"

Below is what the result should look like.

```
target

target
```

How can I achieve this?

thanks for help..

Comment: Do you mean remove all exept third column ?

Comment: is the text "target" known?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this regex for *Find what* field:

```
(?:[^\n|]*?\|){2}\s*([^\n|]*?)\s*\|[^\n|]*?\|
```

Replace with `$1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this

```
[a-zA-Z]*\s\|\s[0-9]*\s\|\s([a-zA-Z]*)\s\|\s[a-zA-Z\:\.\[\]]*\s\|
```

by this

```
\1
```

To remove all exept third column.